# What is the content parameter when creating a new file with Github API?

Tags: git, api, github

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) states that the parameter `content` is the `The new file content, Base64 encoded.`. I don't understand what this is... Are they asking to copy paste the content of the file (which can be more than 10 Mb) into the parameter? Is it some hash of the contents of the file? The `path` field is the path to the file, so the need for a `content` parameter sounds repetitive. I can't figure out from the example (`content: "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM"`) what this is supposed to be... Let's suppose that my file is `foo.txt`:

```
some stupid example. whats the content of this?
```

what's its content in the context of github api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I read the documentation, it looks like the `path` parameter specifies the **path within the repository** where you want the content to go, **NOT the local path** of the file you're trying to upload.

Thus, `content` is the base64 encoded file content, and is not redundant.

Using your example, I'd run the following command to base64 encode and pass that as the `content` parameter.

```
$ base64 foo.txt 
c29tZSBzdHVwaWQgZXhhbXBsZS4gd2hhdHMgdGhlIGNvbnRlbnQgb2YgdGhpcz8K
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still getting an error ("message": "Not Found"): PUT ```https://api.github.com/repos/pedro-roberto/test2/apiFile.txt?content=Zm9vMzQK&message=test&path=apiFile.txt``` don't understand this error, I am creating a new file, so it's normal it doesn't find it

Comment: ok, solved it, need to create an access token. also didn't manage to do it with postman, had to use curl

Comment: @Pedro, Good job determining that; I was going to look into it later, but it looks like you got to it first.